# What happens if I don't follow the instructions on the form?

Tags: headliner

In the sign up form when starting a new game in "headliner" there is a section at the bottom saying "office use only", followed by a do not fill text.

However, it is possible to fill something in here, what happens if you do?

[image: sign up form]